# python with passing keyword urgments

Tags: python

Can anyone help with the following code please  i am getting  "TypeError: mergeSort() got an unexpected keyword argument 'split_by_3'.

```py
def mergeSort(list_of_items, split_by_three): 
    """Takes list and splite by returns sorted list""" 
    start_time = time.time() 
    list_of_items = merg_sort(list_of_items, split_by_three) 
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time 
    return (list_of_items, elapsed_time)

def merg_sort(list_of_items, split_by_3):
    """ Private helper dividing lists in 3"""
    if split_by_3:
        if len(list_of_items) <= 2:
            return list_of_items
        third = len(list_of_items) // 3
        lower_list = list_of_items[:third]
        midle_list = list_of_items[third:third * 2]
        upper_list = list_of_items[third * 2:]
        return merge(merge(merg_sort(lower_list, split_by_3), merg_sort(midle_list, split_by_3)), merg_sort(upper_list, split_by_3))
```

Calling

```py
mergeRes2 = mergeSort(list(list2), split_by_3=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function `mergeSort` which does not have an argument named `split_by_3`. Rather, it has one called `split_by_three`.

So your call should look like this:

`mergeRes2 = mergeSort(list(list2), split_by_three=False)`

Comment: I am sorry for  the confusion,  however, this is a part of the code where the fun name getting called def mergeSort(list_of_items, split_by_three):
    """Takes list and splite by returns sorted list"""
    start_time = time.time()
    list_of_items = merg_sort(list_of_items, split_by_three)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    return (list_of_items, elapsed_time)

Comment: @KibromTeklu The function you're calling has no argument ```split_by_3```. What you need to do is change your call to ```mergeRes2 = mergeSort(list(list2), split_by_three=False)```

Comment: @KibromTeklu You should include all relevant information in the question body rather than in comments to get a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You defined merge_sort but you are calling mergesort